# How to get the value from my component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I created a component that format a date as i want it to but i created another component that is a DateTimePicker using the "react-native-modal-datetime-picker" but with a button that shows the modal and when the user selects the date, it displays at the button the date already formatted and a label above the date.

The problem is that i need that date value on my View, and i don't know how to get that value from my components.

My DateFormatter (i need the value of that text):

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';

export default class DateFormatter extends React.Component {
  formatDate(date){
    if(date==null)
      if(this.props.text!=null)
        return this.props.text;
      else
        return "Selecione uma data";
    else
      return date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <Text style={this.props.style}>
        {this.formatDate(this.props.date)}
      </Text>
    );
  }
}
```

My InputDate (see that i am using my other component):

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, TouchableOpacity, Text, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import DateTimePicker from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker';
import DateFormatter from '../components/DateFormatter';

export default class InputDate extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isDateTimePickerVisible: false,
      date: null,
      showLabel: false
    }
  }

  showDateTimePicker = () => {
    this.setState({isDateTimePickerVisible: true});
  }

  hideDateTimePicker= () => {
    this.setState({isDateTimePickerVisible: false});
  }

  handleDatePicked = (date) => {
    this.setState({date: date});
    this.setState({showLabel: true});
    this.hideDateTimePicker();
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <DateTimePicker isVisible={this.state.isDateTimePickerVisible} onConfirm={this.handleDatePicked} onCancel={() => this.setState({isDateTimePickerVisible: false})} />
        <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5}}>{this.state.showLabel ? "Data da Inspeção" : ""}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.9, height: 40}} onPress={() => this.setState({isDateTimePickerVisible: true})}>
          <DateFormatter date={this.state.date} text={"Data da Inspeção"} style={this.state.date==null ? {fontSize: 16, paddingLeft: 5, color: "#575757"} : {fontSize: 16, paddingLeft: 5, color: "#000"}}/>
          <View style={{backgroundColor: '#dfdfdf', alignSelf: 'stretch', height: 1, marginTop: 5}}></View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And in my view, i am just using `<InputDate />`. How can i get the value from the InputDate component and use in my view?

Answer (score 1):

You need to hoist the formatted date value up through the components via state/props. The Date Formatter component will do the formatting and then pass the value to the Input date component via a props function that saves it in its state. You can use this method again to update the Input Dates parent component state.

Date Formatter

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';

export default class DateFormatter extends React.Component {
  formatDate(date){
    if(date==null)
      if(this.props.text!=null)
        return this.props.text;
      else
        return "Selecione uma data";
    else
      return date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      // Update parent component state
      this.props.handleDateFormat(this.formatDate(this.props.date));
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <Text style={this.props.style}>
        {this.formatDate(this.props.date)}
      </Text>
    );
  }
}
```

Input Date

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, TouchableOpacity, Text, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import DateTimePicker from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker';
import DateFormatter from '../components/DateFormatter';

export default class InputDate extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isDateTimePickerVisible: false,
      date: null,
      showLabel: false,
      formattedDate: null
    }
  }

  showDateTimePicker = () => {
    this.setState({isDateTimePickerVisible: true});
  }

  hideDateTimePicker= () => {
    this.setState({isDateTimePickerVisible: false});
  }

  handleDatePicked = (date) => {
    this.setState({date: date});
    this.setState({showLabel: true});
    this.hideDateTimePicker();
  }

  handleDateFormat = (formattedDate) => {
      this.setState({
          formattedDate: formattedDate
      })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <DateTimePicker handleDateFormat={this.handleDateFormat} isVisible={this.state.isDateTimePickerVisible} onConfirm={this.handleDatePicked} onCancel={() => this.setState({isDateTimePickerVisible: false})} />
        <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5}}>{this.state.showLabel ? "Data da Inspeção" : ""}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.9, height: 40}} onPress={() => this.setState({isDateTimePickerVisible: true})}>
          <DateFormatter date={this.state.date} text={"Data da Inspeção"} style={this.state.date==null ? {fontSize: 16, paddingLeft: 5, color: "#575757"} : {fontSize: 16, paddingLeft: 5, color: "#000"}}/>
          <View style={{backgroundColor: '#dfdfdf', alignSelf: 'stretch', height: 1, marginTop: 5}}></View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't make sense. You are passing the 'handleDateFormat' to the DateTimePicker component but you are using the 'handleDateFormat' inside the DateFormatter component. But ok, I put everything in the right place, but how can I take my date in my view? I need to get the date through the DateInput component

Comment: We're passing the `handleDateFormat` function as a prop to the DateTimePicker component. Then inside the DateTimePicker component, you are calling that function from props, and passing the formatted date in as a param. That triggers the `handleDateFormat` function on the InputDate component that sets the InputDate formattedDate state to what the DateTimePicker passed in. Another option would be to move the `handleDateFormat` function to the parent component of InputDate, and then just pass it through InputDate to DateTimePicker and do the same thing (update state of parent through props).